# how to seperate form into 2 parts for requiring different inputs

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, required

I am trying to separate my form for creating log in and sign up in different divs. I created the inputs with a required tag for validating the data. Although when I am submitting one of the forms it's automatically trying to validate the other and therefore makes an error.(the other part of the form is not filled)

> aspx

```
    <form id="form1" method="get" runat="server">
    <div id="hideAndSeek">
        <div id="returnPic"><a href="homePage.aspx"><img src="returnPic-removebg-preview.png" width="60" height="60" /></a></div>
        <div id="rightPart"><img src="doctorPicBlue.png" width="700" height="600" id="signPic" /></div>

        <div id="motivachia">
            <p>"Doctors you need,</p><p>when you need them."</p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" id="signUpButton" onclick="hideSignDiv();">sign up</button>
        <button type="button" id="logInButton" onclick="hideLogDiv();">log in</button>
    </div>
 <div id="hideLogDiv">
        <div id="xSymbolLogDiv"><img src="xSymbol-removebg-preview.png" id="logxSymbol" onclick="logXclick();" /></div>
        <div id="logInCoteret"><h1><u>log in</u></h1></div>
        <div><asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" OnClientClick="return valid();" OnClick="Button3_Click" Text="next" name="submitLogButton" /></div>
```

// the second part of the form

```
    <div id="hideSignDiv">
     
        <div><asp:Button  ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClientClick="return valid();" OnClick="Button1_Click"  text="next" name="submitSignButton"/></div>

            <select id="lanSelect" name="lanSelect" onclick="languageClick();" required="required" >
                <option style="display:none" value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Languages...</option>
                <option value="6">Hebrew</option>
                <option value="1">Arabic</option>
                <option value="2">English</option>
         
            </select>
        </div>

        <div id="signExpLabel"><label> * You must choose an expertise</label></div>
        <div>
            <select id="expSelect" name="expSelect" onclick="expertiseClick();" required="required" >
                <option style="display:none" value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Your expertise...</option>
                <option value="7">Oncology</option>
                <option value="8">Pathological anatomy</option>

            </select>
        </div>

    </div>
 </form>
```

Comment: Why dont you use two forms?

Comment: Can I????????????\

Comment: I have tried and it is not working.

Comment: Put one form into each div you're showing/hiding. Can you post the code that is not working and the exact error?

Comment: The code is working. The problem is that when I'm trying to submit one of the parts of the forms it requires the validation of the second part.

Comment: Ok, edit your post with your model data